# How to inherit referenced assemblies in NuGet package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

Simple question. I have a NuGet package project. This project references other class library projects (they are not NuGet Packages). I would like my NuGet package to load its references DLL's into the project installing the package. Is this possible, or do all my referenced class libraries need to be NuGet packages in order to specify them as dependencies?

TIA

Comment: You can do that if you include your referenced dlls and main project into one nuget package and set `references`, [see assembly references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#explicit-assembly-references)

Comment: Does this reference dlls in the bin?

Comment: I posted as answer It's more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your referenced dlls as files to nuspec and can set immediately source path file and target path file inside a nuget package. Next you should add references to this files in nuspec. It looks like this (I removed other metadatas):

.nuspec

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    ...
    <references>
      <reference file="First.dll" />
      <reference file="Second.dll" />
    </references>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="SomePath\First.dll" target="lib\First.dll" />
    <file src="SomePath\Second.dll" target="lib\Second.dll" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 2):

When performing a `nuget pack` command, you can specify the option [IncludeReferencedProjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference).

From the docs:

> Indicates that the built package should include referenced projects either as dependencies or as part of the package. If a referenced project has a corresponding .nuspec file that has the same name as the project, then that referenced project is added as a dependency. Otherwise, the referenced project is added as part of the package.