# How can I create a nuget package that shares source files?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, csproj

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to create a nuget package that can be used to share dependencies that really are a concern of development, not consumers. Our team has a set of `Check` (or `Guard` or `Ensure` etc) methods that we use in all of our projects. Right now we simply copy the csharp file from one repo to another and reference them from all the projects in that repo by manually modifying the csproj to include:

```
<Compile Include="..\Shared\Check.cs" Link="Properties\Check.cs" />
```

Ideally I would like to create a nuget package so that we can version these classes, but I don't want the nuget package to show up as a dependency for every project we write. There used to be a way to include source files in a nuget package, but that doesn't seem to be supported anymore.

Is there a proper way to do this now?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set files directly that will be included to nuget packages? If so you can do that using a `.nuspec` file.

Comment: You can execute PowerShell script when Nuget package is installed, inside this script you may modify project files and perform any other operations like downloading sources and adding them to a project. But be aware that this is not the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: A similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112285/how-to-inherit-referenced-assemblies-in-nuget-package/45112848#45112848) how you can do that with `.nuspec` file.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria That is a useful feature, however wouldnt you run into versioning issues if you have multiple libraries that include different version of the same dll?

Comment: It's not a problem until you can have two different version of the same dll to output folder (you cannot have two the same files in one folder). If I right remember two files with the same names but with different file versions are different files and they can locate in one folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `contentFiles` secttion into `.nuspec` file. Here is a full example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata minClientVersion="3.3.0">
    <id>ContentFilesExample</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>nuget</authors>
    <!-- The NuGet team authored this package -->
    <owners>nuget</owners>
    <!-- The NuGet team owns this package -->
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>A content v2 example package.</description>
    <tags>contentv2 contentFiles</tags>
    <!-- Build actions for items in the contentFiles folder -->
    <contentFiles>
      <!-- Include Assets as Content -->
      <files include="**/images/*.*" buildAction="EmbeddedResource" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

With NuGet 2.x and earlier, and projects using packages.config, the  `files` element is also used to include immutable content files when a package is installed. With NuGet 3.3+ and projects using project.json pr PackageReference, the `contentFiles` element is used instead.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria thank you for letting me know. I've just edited the answer. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: This does not work with the new csproj project system in 2017. Do you know of a way to make it work?

Comment: It depends on the version of your nuget. I'll update the answer

Comment: It appears there is a bug in the dotnet sdk which is the reason this doesnt work for me with the new csproj. It looks like the fix will be in 2.2.0. https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1100. I will mark this answer since it is correct, its dotnet that has a bug. To make it work, you have to set the following csproj property: `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>`